# Localizing ASP.NET MVC application in Azure not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, localization

I'm trying to localize my ASP.NET MVC application.

I have created an Action Filter called **Internationalization**:

```
public class InternationalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("lang");
        string language = cookie == null ? "en" : cookie.Value;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format(language));
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format(language));
    }
}
```

I have a **BaseController** class that uses this filter:

```
[Internationalization]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

I'm setting the **lang** cookie in an **ActionResult** in my **HomeController**:

```
public ActionResult SetLanguage(string lang)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("lang", lang);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return this.Redirect(this.Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath);
}
```

I have also added the following to the **<system.web>** of my **Web.config**:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
```

Finally, I've created the necessary resources in my **App_GlobalResources** folder and am using them in my pages.

This all works well when I build the application locally - I switch to a new language using a drop-down that calls the **SetLanguage** action, and the language of the application changes to the selected language.

But once I deploy to Azure, the same approach no longer works. The application stays in the default language (English) even though the cookie is set.

I would be really grateful if anyone can shed some light on the matter. Suggestions on a better way to achieve the same effect would also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try removing the "globalization"  node from the web.config with the rest of the code on (the BaseController)?

Comment: How many languages do you use? Is it the switch between the language to display that dosent work or is it that it uses the wrong language when switching? What is not working? It could be so many things :)

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you haven't setup your global resources to be built and deployed correctly. Have a look at http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx.

Do note that it is better to use resources in their own assembly to ensure they are deployed with (and accessible by) your MVC project.